# System.FormatException of a string

Tags: c#, string.format, formatexception

I'm getting System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format when running this method.

The values of the fields:

```
arrayName = "requester";
fieldList = "\"name\" : \"shimshon\""; // "name" : "shimshon"


public override string ToString()
{
   var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : { {1} }", arrayName, fieldList);

   return val;
}
```

the expect result of the method is

```
"requester" : { "name" : "shimshon" }
```

What is wrong with this format?

Comment: While this is not pertaining to the question at hand, from a general observation it appears you are attempting to create some kind of JSON object.  I would recommend creating a class with the properties needed and use some kind of library such as JSON.net to serialize that into a JSON string, it will save . If that's not what you are attempting to do then ignore this comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : {{ {1} }}", arrayName, fieldList);
```

Note the doubled `{{` and `}}` which is the escape sequence necessary to get braces literally into the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : {{ {1} }}", arrayName, fieldList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : { {1} }", arrayName, fieldList);

    return val;
}
```

on:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : {{ {1} }}", arrayName, fieldList);

   return val;
}
```

> The way escaped braces are interpreted can lead to unexpected results. For example, 
>   consider the format item "{{{0:D}}}", which is intended to display an opening brace, a 
>   numeric value formatted as a decimal number, and a closing brace. However, the format 
>   item is actually interpreted in the following manner:

- The first two opening braces ("{{") are escaped and yield one opening brace.
- The next three characters ("{0:") are interpreted as the start of a format item.
- The next character ("D") would be interpreted as the Decimal standard numeric format specifier, but the next two escaped braces ("}}") yield a single brace. Because the resulting string ("D}") is not a standard numeric format specifier, the resulting string is interpreted as a custom format string that means display the literal string "D}".
- The last brace ("}") is interpreted as the end of the format item.
- The final result that is displayed is the literal string, "{D}". The numeric value that was to be formatted is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `{` and `}` chars that are not part of the format.

```
string.Format("\"{0}\" : {{ {1} }}",.....)
```

See this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a
>   format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are
>   encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the curly brackets that you want to be curly brackets in your output by using double brackets:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   var val = string.Format("\"{0}\" : {{ {1} }}", arrayName, fieldList);

   return val;
}
```